# Getting Errors when switching between functions in Lua?

Tags: lua

This is for a game however I think all of the rules apply. I have a function which is

```
function nolag()
    if !nolag then 
        nolag = true
        ply:ConCommand("ax_stoplag")
    elseif nolag then 
        nolag = false
        ply:ConCommand("ax_resetlag")
    end
end
```

The `ply:ConCommand("ax_stoplag")` is basically another term for `print ("ax_stoplag")` in my situation. However I have a button

```
CreateButton( "No-Lag", MISCtab, black, tblack, true, 355, 130, 95, 20, "Toggle No-Lag on and off", function () nolag() end )
```

So that will create a button that will then link to the `nolag` function. However I can click it, but when I click it again nothing happens and I get an error (error in game). And basically the `nolag = true` and the `nolag = false` is the problem and is causing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined, nolag as function.

Doing `if !nolag then` which should be `if not nolag then` in lua,

basically checks if nolag is not set (if it was not set, then this statement will return true).

Afterwards you are setting nolag (function variable) to true/false that means next button click,

Your application will crash, try one of these 2 options.

```
local _nolag = false;
function nolag()
    if(not _nolag) then
        _nolag = not _nolag -- or _nolag = true;
        ply:ConCommand("ax_stoplag");
    else -- no need if here, assuming _nolag will always be true or false;
        _nolag = not _nolag
        ply:ConCommand("ax_resetlag");
    end
end


local _nolag = false;
function nolag()
    _nolag = not _nolag;
    ply:ConCommand(_nolag and "ax_resetlag" or "ax_stoplag);
end
```

Comment: You are a life saver! It works now. Thank-you very much. I can see what I did wrong now I have seen that. Thanks

Comment: You've identified the problem but keep in mind: variables don't have types, values do; `function nolog()`... (when executed) assigns the variable `nolag` a function value.